# Row to Column in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table:

table1

```
record   va  textv numv datev
1        1   a     NULL NULL
1        2   NULL  1    NULL
1        3   NULL  NULL 1 jan 2015
2        1   b     NULL NULL
2        2   NULL  45   NULL
3        1   c     NULL NULL
3        3   NULL  NULL 5 feb 2015
```

I need to convert to:

```
va1 va2 va3
a   1   1 jan 2015
b   45  NULL
c   NULL 5 Feb 2015
```

How can I do this in Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 0):

you may use below query:

```
WITH Q1 as
(select record, max (textv) over (partition by record order by va) va1
,max (numv) over (partition by record order by va) va2
max (datev) over (partition by record order by va) va3
)
select distinct record,va1,va2,va3 from Q1;
```